# Magento: Sort a product_collection on final_price

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Im trying to list the lowest priced products among the best selling ones but I cant get Magento to sort on final price.

This is my code:

```
$low_price_products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
   ->setStoreId($storeId)
   ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addOrderedQty($this->date_from, $this->date_to)
   ->addFinalPrice()
   ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
   ->addFieldToFilter('sku',array("in"=>$sku_array))
   ->setOrder('final_price', 'asc')
   ->setPageSize($productCount);
```

I have suspitions that it has got to do with the reports/product_collection. If I knew how to sort the product collection afterwards I could do that but I cant find any good answers on that either.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check SQL query command using

```
$low_price_products->getSelectSql(true);
```

you'll see that final price is generated in the SQL query.
Therefore, it is better if you accomplish sort by price

```
$low_price_products
    ->getSelect()
    ->order('price_index.final_price', 'asc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these..

`->addAttributeToSort('final_price', 'asc')`